# How do I efficiently store time consuming R scripts in a package?

Tags: r

I am working with a large set of survey data files. An essential part of the work flow is recoding values in each file to provide uniform names and uniform value categories.
The data files are currently stored in a package that I use basically for data storage and transfer.

Currently I have an R project that loads the package with the data files and then runs a recode script for each data file. This is a very time consuming process and I would like to simplify this.

Is it possible to move the recode scripts into the data storage package so that they run once and then spit out .rda files that can be loaded in an Rproject ready for analysis?

I feel like this is not a task for package functions as each recode script is tailored to one particular data file.

I have read that RScripts can be stored in the inst folder. Would that help me here? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: There are pacakges like [nycflights](https://github.com/tidyverse/nycflights13) that only have data. If you see their source, they have a "data-raw" folder where they store the raw data and have scripts to turn them into .rda files. That process happens when the package is built so only the rda files are actually included in the package. Maybe that pattern can work for you as well.

Comment: That is interesting. I guess it would be nice to have it set up so that recodes could only be run *once* and then have an rda file with those recodes spit out. But going forward we will be adding additional recodes to facilitate new common variables. Will all the old recodes need to be run at install? 

The cgwtools::resave() command at the end of each script might be nice because it will only modify existing rdata objects, not rewrite them. That way, previous recodes executed on previous installs could be commented out.